# Getting FQDN on new server with systemd using Java

Tags: java, hostname, systemd, fqdn

On our deployment systems we are using Java to get the fully qualified domain name for the deployment machine we're using.

We're using the following method: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName--

After moving to new servers we have issue related to systemd that it doesn't resolve the domain :

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: *machineName*: Name or service not known
```

This is the only difference between the old lab we used and the new one that our IT department could think of.

I've looked online for 2 days for any solution but couldn't find what is the best course of action.

Any ideas?

*Edit question:*

Some outputs I've tried -

```
root@myd-vm11924:~# hostname
myd-vm11924
root@myd-vm11924:~# hostname -a
hostname: Name or service not known
root@myd-vm11924:~# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: myd-vm11924
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
           Boot ID: ef97951ccad04febb9856013e750e9ee
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
      Architecture: x86_64
root@myd-vm11924:~#
```

TIA.

Comment: It's unusual that you are running systemd on Ubuntu 14.04. It didn't become the default init system until a later release. Maybe that's somehow related. Have you tried the code on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with what out IT approves, and they supply the templates and Os versions we're using (due to security requirements, etc.) I can't provision 16.04 as they are not supporting it yet. trying to get budget to work with AWS but no luck on that front :)

Answer (score 1):

First I would reality check that other tools are returning the hostname as expected. In particular, the legacy Hostname reporting tool:

```
hostname
```

And the new systemd-specific tool for this:

```
hostnamectl
```

If these report the right answer and Java doesn't, you have the possibility of adding a workarond in your code to make a system call to these tools which return the correct response.

Otherwise, you can file a bug with your Java tools provider.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I've already tried it but you're right - I should have mentioned it and post it - edited my answer :)